# How do I eliminate EAGAIN errors on blocking send() calls on Linux

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to write a test program that writes data across a TCP socket through Localhost on a Linux machine (CentOS 6.5 to be exact).  I have one program writing, and one program reading.  The reading is done via non-blocking recv() calls triggered from an epoll.  There are enough cores on the machine to handle all CPU load without contention or scheduling issues.

The sends are buffers of smaller packets (about 100 bytes), aggregated up to 1400 bytes.  Changing to aggregate larger (64K) buffers makes no apparent difference.  When I do the sends, after 10s of MB of data, I start getting EAGAIN errors on the sender.  Verifying via fcntl, I am definitiely configured as a blocking socket.  I also noticed that calling ioctl(SIOCOUTQ) whenever I get EAGAIN yields larger and larger numbers.

The receiver is slower in processing the data read than the sender is in creating the data.  Adding receiver threads is not an option.  The fact that it is slower is OK assuming I can throttle the sender.

Now, my understanding of blocking sockets is that a send() should block in the send until the data goes out (this is based upon past experience) - meaning, the tcp stack should force the input side to be self-throttling.

Also, the Linux manual page for send() (and other queries on the web) indicate that EAGAIN is only returned for non-blocking sockets.

Can anyone give me some understanding as to what is going on, and how I can get my send() to actually block until enough data goes out for me to put more in.  I would rather not have to rework the logic to put usleep() or other things in the code.  It is a lightly loaded system, yield() is insufficient to allow it to drain.

Comment: I would run the program in `gdb`, and see whether the `EAGAIN` is being passed up directly from the kernel into libc, or whether something inside libc is causing it.

Comment: @utility If the socket is really in blocking mode, your citation is irrelevant. But it's hard to believe.

Comment: Hmm. I just looked at how glibc implements `socket` on x86 Linux. It's a very, very thin layer over a `socketcall` syscall. It doesn't look like blocking/non-blocking sockets are implemented in libc at all. I don't think this error could originate in libc -- it looks like it must be bubbling up from the kernel.

Comment: Do you have a timeout on the socket? See e.g. `SO_SNDTIMEO` in `socket(7)`.

Comment: @Ulfalizer, no I don't.

Comment: @AlexD - send() is a system call.  There should be no code between the syscall() and my code.  I also guarantee that the errno is set inside the cal to send().  I will see about running through strace tomorrow to confirm, but am afraid that strace will slow it down too much.

Comment: @Alex D, it is bubbling up from the kernel.  My understanding from the kernel documentation, libc documentation, and other network programming sources is that a blocking socket should never receive an EAGAIN.  We actually saw this on a live customer system when they had a network glitch.  The data rates are relatively low on a 1GB network, but, other traffic appears to cause a problem.  After a few minutes, it appears to clear up, now that my code does retries and delays.

Comment: Although you're not setting a timeout, could you check `getsockopt(..., SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, ...)` just to see what it returns?

Comment: This would be much easier to debug if you could compile and run a custom kernel on the host which is experiencing the problem.

Comment: Can't build a custom kernel.  It's occurring on a customer's machine.  They don't even like us to install software like htop on it :(.  I'll consider the other code change for checking timeout when I am next in the code.